# I need to add data to a FabricJS object and use them when exporting the canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

**This is the function I use to add an object:**

```
function _addImageObject(imageURL) {
  fabric.util.loadImage(imageURL, function (imageLoaded) {

    var image = new fabric.Image(imageLoaded);

    image.set({
      borderColor: 'black',
      cornerColor: 'black',
      cornerStrokeColor: 'white',
      cornerSize: 11,
      transparentCorners: false,
    });

    canvas.add(image);
    canvas.centerObject(image);
    canvas.setActiveObject(image);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
}
```

**Function used to get the objects:**

```
 function _canvasJSON() {
      try {
        let canvasCopy = _copyCanvas(canvas);

        let canvasJSON = {
          canvasImage: JSON.stringify(canvasCopy),
          svg: canvas.toSVG()
        };
        return canvasJSON;
      } catch (e) {
        canvas.renderAll();
      }
    }

function _copyCanvas() {
     let canvasString = JSON.stringify(canvas);
     return JSON.parse(canvasString);
}
```

**I'd like to add an object inside this image, just like this:**

```
image.set('key', { values: 123});
```

And be able to get it from the return of `_canvasJSON()`.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to add/get any custom key&value pair to any fabricJS object, you can do that as you do with any other key&value pair:

```
image.set('width', 100);
image.get('width');

image.set('customKey', 'Custom value added here');
image.get('customKey');

image.set({
  borderColor: 'black',
  values: 123
  transparentCorners: false,
});
image.get('values');
```

If you need to export a fabricJS canvas, use this:

```
const customKeys = ['customKey', 'values'];
canvas.toJSON(customKeys);
```

`toJSON()` accepts an array as a parameter. That array **MUST** include any custom key that you've attached to any object. It also needs any key that it's not part of the 'default' keys from an object(e.g: 'evented', hoverCursor', 'scaleX', etc.)

use `canvas.loadFromJSON(json)` to load the exported json.

More details about toJSON [in the documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON).